# Moving a row from one sheet to another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with two pages, one initial list and the other one the destination list. I need a code that move a row to the destination list when that specific row checkbox in the base list is marked as true.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const jobdoneColumn = 1;
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "BASE LIST" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "Done") {
    let vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    let dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("DESTINATION LIST");
    dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1,vs.length,vs[0].length ).setValues(vs);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

I tried this code but it seems like the range part doesn't work.

Here's the link to access the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LW0wTigo7XLQOJ-UtLutFkzByKaSG5ucndVU9LEzgQQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello! I've seen your example sheet and has now a whole different code, is it working now??

Comment: Hello! Yeah, the checkbox part is now working, i'm having other problem now with the other code name "REGISTRAR ENTRADA", where the appendRow part in that code skips the row if there's a unmarked checkbox in it. Do you know if there is a way to use appendRow in a specific range? Like just inside B2:F500 range so it ignores the checkboxes?

Comment: What exactly is the function of `criarRegistro`? Please update your question.